# How to write a file in a GCS bucket using Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

New to Airflow here.

I have a Python code that reads a BigQuery table, makes some transformations as a pandas DataFrame and save it as a file.

Using Airflow, I need a DAG that executes my code and save it as a file in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The Airflow is deployed on Composer.

How am I supposed to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If your transformation can be expressed in BigQuery QL you can use BQ to GCS operator:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html

Examples here:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_bigquery_to_gcs.py

If you need to to do more complex transformation that you have no external service that you can orchestrate, create a custom operator that uses BigQuery Hook and GCS Hook and does what you want to do. It is easier than you think - just take a look at the BQToGCS operator and you will see that it's rather straightforward.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs.py

Airflow is all Python - so it does not really change much if you compose existing operators in a DAG, or write your own operators (and then compose them). It's all python code. Airflow implemented Hook abstractions, specifically for the reason to be able to hide the complexity of communication with the services, but allow you as the DAG/Operator's writer to write the operator's  code using the hooks and doing some extra operations.